# Criteria API ignores JOIN

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink, inner-join

I have a simple criteria api query with a (inner) join

```
public void find(Category category) {
 CriteriaBuilder b = getQueryBuilder();
 CriteriaQuery<Product> q = createQuery();
 Root<Product> root = q.from(Product.class);
 Join<Product, Category> myCategory= root.join("category");        
 q.where(b.equal(myCategory, category));
 entityManager.createQuery(q).getResultList();
}
```

The query works, but if I enable in persistence.xml the sql logging I can see that the query is a

```
SELECT * FROM product, category WHERE ...
```

and no

```
SELECT * FROM product join category on category.id = product.category ...
```

Any idea what the reason for this is? The where statement is very slow, so a real join would be really better.

I'm using eclipselink 2.5.1, Java EE7 and postgres

I also have a superclass from Product

```
@Entity
@Audit
public class SuperClass {}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Product extends SuperClass {}
```

But this should be no problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A join is actual being perform, however the SQL used to perform the join is written in implicit join notation.  The join will have the same performance as explicit join notation (notation using JOIN and ON).  A "real" join is being performed, however it is just not in the explicit join notation (aka ANSI SQL 92) you expect.

Comment: I'm not sure, do you say that "join on" syntax is the same as all over "where"? There is a big performance difference. Everything over where does compare everything with everything and this makes it slow. I can say this with the answertime by the database over where is slow, with "join on" it is fast

Comment: @user3263327 What are you not sure about?

Comment: okay, so you are right, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join 
I have to read a little bit more about joins. I think I have to change the join type (no more inner join)

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting from `Root` with `Product.class`, but you need to select from join.
And I think result of you join must be mapped to some class, containing both entities `Product` and `Category`. If you like to get only product from join you can write something like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder b = getQueryBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Product> q1 = createQuery();
CriteriaQuery<Product> q2 = createQuery();
Root<Product> root = q1.from(Product.class);        
q2.select(root.as(Product.class)).from(root.join("category"))
entityManager.createQuery(q2).getResultList();
```